# show the Add member employes in other page

Tags: string

i have create the card in js  and inside card we have to add the members on click button after adding the member add member button will be show remove member auto in button and in header there will be 3 option myteam aboutus or  info ,when w click on myteam it will show team detail in other page .

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.